# Sign a document and verify Date of signature (openssl)

Tags: linux, security, openssl

First off: openssl's options make my head spin :)

I have a file that I want to sign (foo.doc), and at some point in the future I want to prove the date/time the file was signed. How do I do this?

I followed some neat instructions on how to sign files, which was great, but after googling I can't find out how to verify its signed timestamp.

- https://www.zimuel.it/blog/sign-and-verify-a-file-using-openssl

The "openssl dgst -sha256 -verify ..." works out fine, but not date is printed.

I'm using linux.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RFC 3161 "Internet X.509 Public Key Infrastructure Time-Stamp Protocol". openssl supports it with [openssl-ts, ts - Time Stamping Authority tool](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ts.html)